# What is the difference in accessing an external string from a resource using a different method?

Tags: android, string, localization

In my current application, I am implementing localization. I came across various ways to access the string (external string). Some methods are:

1. Accessing directly using R.string.hello
2. Using getResourse().getString(R.string.hello)
3. getString.
4. The Eclipse tool to externalize resources, which creates a message.property file and access the string from a snippet.

The main confusion is between 1 and 2. If I use "1" that is accessing directly, can I get resources based on locale?

Comment: Can you explain the differences between points 1 and 3?

Comment: @DmitryArc  honestly i really don't know about point 3. I found this in net surfing

Comment: I am  confused between 1. and 2, Are they same thing or logically different. The problem is that i am accessing string using both type of code.

Comment: Please see my explanation. 1 and 2 are the same thing.

Comment: Agree with Fadils.These are really the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

It *doesn't matter* whether you use `R.string.hello` or `getResources().getString(R.string.hello)`.
Both will point the same thing.

So, yes, for your localization, then it will point to the right stuff.
It's been taken care of.

### Some trivial stuff:

`R.string.hello` is actually an integer.
And most methods, that are used by passing `R.string.hello` (or other resources) as its argument, basically have the function to translate to corresponding string of the number.

Let's take [TextView](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) as an example.

It has two methods for setText.

First:

```
public final void setText(CharSequence text)
```

Second:

```
public final void setText(int resid)
```

So, when you call using `getResources().getString()`:

```
myTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hello);
```

Then the first method is called.

And when you call using `R.string.hello` directly, then the second method is called.

If you take a look closer to the source, the second method's content (calling using `R.string.hello` directly) is actually calling the first method.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L4133

Both are provided for our convenience, so that we can use either direct resource `R.string.hello` or using `getResources().getString(R.string.hello)`.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of Context method getString():

```
 /**
 * Return a localized string from the application's package's
 * default string table.
 *
 * @param resId Resource id for the string
 */
public final String getString(int resId) {
    return getResources().getString(resId);
}
```

So it's the same as using `getResourse().getString(R.string.hello)` (2), and it returns the result in the proper locale.

Comment: what if i access string directly using R.string.something. is this same as accessing from proper locale

Comment: R.string.something it's not the String value itself. It is an integer identifier of this resource in your package. You should use it to access it's value using system interface getString()